# DesktopBrowser version on IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I can change the version of mobile app via application descriptror

For example :

```
<android version="1.0.16.2">
<blackberry10 version="1.0.1.2"/>
<iphone  version="1.0.16.2">
```

My question :
Can i change the desktopBrowser version via application descriptor ?

Answer (score 0):

The `version` attribute of the DesktopBrowser environment in application-descriptor.xml has no meaning. It is a relic that should be removed from the XML's scheme.

You do not change its version. It has no version. It is always 'latest'.